# Cocos2d 0.99.5 supports ipad retina display?

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I wonder if the cocos2d 0.99.5 supports iPad retina display. If not, is there any way to include that support to it?

Thanks!

Comment: upgrade to v1.0 - that's absolutely doable in a day (or less). I ouldn't use v1.1 though if you use CCAnimation a lot (timing is off)

Comment: I would like to use GBox2d a Box2d wrapper developed by Andreas Loew. When I upgrade to version 1.0 or 2.x of cocos2d, appear several errors. As I am new in development, I don't know how to fix this and have not found an updated version of this wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d 0.99.5 does not support iPad Retina out of the box. You can use a few [category classes](https://github.com/sdesimone/iOSSnippets/blob/master/cocos2D/CCFileUtils+SDSDeviceSuffix.m) I wrote to make this possible.

For (slightly) more info, check my [blog entry](http://labs.freescapes.org/blog/main/cocos2d-and-the-new-retina-ipad-take-2/) about the matter.

Hope it helps.